# Stuck in catch-22 trying to fix radiator leak

Tags: radiator, leak, coolant-leak, flush

I'm trying to use a stop-leak solution to fix a leak in the radiator, but I'm stuck in a catch-22.

The stop-leak instructions say to flush the coolant system if it is dirty or clogged. I don't know if it is, but I figured it couldn't hurt, and the flush+cleaner was cheap, so I got it. The problem is that the flush+cleaner instructions say to pour it into the radiator and run the car for a while.

This doesn't make sense. I have to flush the radiator before I use the stop-leak, but if I pour the flush+cleaner into the radiator, it will just pour out the bottom if I don't use the stop-leak first.

What should I do to get out of this infinite loop?

Comment: Is the leak in the radiator itself, or is it just a hose hanging off? I'd recommend NOT using a stop-leak as I've never got them to work for me. As for how to use it, literally the flush+clean and run the engine. Whether or not it drains out doesn't matter too much so long as it's in there long enough to allow the engine to run ten minutes. If it's gonna empty before ten minutes pass, I'd not bother with stop-leak and go for a new radiator.

Comment: Agree with @yollooool here ... stop-leak is just a band-aid. Figure out what the real issue is (if you don't know already) and get it fixed. I've never really had good luck with stop-leak either, and I've tried many different brands/types. You know what the definition of insanity is, right? *Doing the same thing over again expecting different results*. If so, I'm completely nuts.

Comment: They say run the car for a while as the sealer needs to be heated to coagulate and stick, then eventually seal the hole... If the leak you are trying to fix is larger than a pin-hole then it won't work... You need to do the job properly.. Mind you I did see a tractor radiator with a branch hammered into it once...

Comment: @SolarMike Going full RoyalNavalRepairs there, lol. That's actually how the UK Royal Navy repair their ships upon being damaged by missiles; chunks of wood hammered into the damage. That being said, that's against saltwater that's cold, not hot, coolant-containing water. :P 

The stop-leak, as you say, would only work on tiny, tiny leaks. It may be worth chucking one in to repair any other damage throughout the rest of the system, but if the radiator is leaking so fast that 10 minutes depletes enough to stop you running the engine, there's a serious problem that needs fixing FAST.

Comment: I don't know if it would drain that fast; I was just assuming. I have read both good and bad reviews of stop-leak solutions, including people saying that they had a leak again after some time. The car isn't used much (~1,000KM/year), so I figured it should last a while. Anyway, I tried to get a look again today and I think it might be the hose, but the weather hasn't been cooperating, so I haven't been able to lift the car to get a proper look from beneath. I still have the receipts, so I'll put off using them until I can confirm it's not the hose.

Comment: If it is leaking so bad that it is visibly pouring out then "stop leak" isn't going to fix it.

Comment: I finally got a chance to get under the car today, and I was thinking the same thing. It isn't just a drip, it pours right out. So I'm guessing it might be a loose or broken hose. I've also read it could be the head gasket. Either way, it shouldn't be too expensive to fix right? Also, do I have to tow the car to the mechanic or would it be possible to drive while keeping an eye on the temperature?